# Jquery data-bind to a unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I'm adding data to my unordered list like this:

```
<ul id="mychats"></ul>
```

```js
if (obj.request_type == 'client_information') {
    $("#mychats").children().remove();

    $.each(obj.clients_information, function (index, data) {
        var li = "<li class='not_selected' id='" + data.chatid + "'>" + data.client_name;

        if (data.status == 0) //Chat is unlocked
            li += " <img class='chat_status' src='https://www.astro.ru.nl/lopes/_media/intra.png?w=&h=&cache=cache' />";
        else
            li += " <img class='chat_status' src='https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/686859081/page-restrictions-padlock-icon.png?api=v2' />";

        li += "</li>";
        $("#mychats").append(li);
    });
}
```

This works as intended but I want to do it in a different way, I want to bind the `ul` with the data in `obj.clients.informations` directly.

Sample JSON data in `obj`:

```
{
    "request_type": "client_information",
    "clients_information": [{
        "chatid": "0a9ef3c4-b34a-435f-b0c5-15bf415e1517",
        "client_name": "awd",
        "status": 0
    },{
        "chatid": "08a725c4-4fd1-471d-a507-4782f6bbc774",
        "client_name": "awdaeqdaw",
        "status": 0
    }]
}
```

something like:

```
<ul id='mychats' data-bind='foreach: Clients' data-role='listview'>
    <li data-binding='class: thisclass, id: chatid, text: client_name'></li>
</li>
```

With the specified code in jQuery to be able to bind it to the unordered list. I tried to search all over the net and I couldn't really find an example for jQuery.

Just this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4FdcY/ (i want something like this for my object)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example uses the knockoutjs library. The documentation on the website is spot on and is exactly what youre after.

Just parse your json in to an object and use knockout to bind the object to the markup.

Comment: can i do it inside a jquery function?

Comment: I only use Jquery  for the $(document).ready(....) where i will create an instance of the view model, call a method on the view model to get the data, put it in an observable array which is bound to the UI, then call ko.applyBindings(viewModel). Then all your data would appear in the UI like magic.